# Call delegate method with controls asynchronously in a C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, delegates

I am developping a WPF application. 
I have a couple of timers that work asynchronously and they are created with System.Threading.Timer objects.

```
new System.Threading.Timer(
                    new System.Threading.TimerCallback(Timer_Function),
                    null,
                    timing,
                    timing
                );

Timer_Function()
{
  /*code that runs asynchronously */
}
```

In order to update the controls that are in WPF view I use delegate methods called by Dispatcher.Invoke otherwise the compiler would raise InvalidOperationException (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.)

My problem is that the delegate method do not run asynchronously and i have to do a lot of work in it so the application stops.

What can i do to run delegate method asynchronously?

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :-). Altready tried but it is still not working.

Comment: Is the problem that the code in the Timer_Function does not really run async? Where is the part that "does a lot of work"?

Comment: Timer_Function runs async. It is when the funtion calls a delegate method (where i have to do the big part of the execution) with the dispatcher (Dispatcher.Invoke) that the problem comes out.
I need to use a delegate because i have to update some controls and in Timer_Funcition it is forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is separate out your business logic for determining what you should display, from the code that displays the results of those calculations to the UI.  The business logic, the non-UI code, should be run in a non-UI thread and compute some result.  That result should then be given to a method that will marshal to the UI thread and then display those results.

Comment: Yes. In the end I ended up re-writing a solution like you suggest. I put almost all the code that i had in the delegate in the Timer_Function (the method runned by the thread), and i made for every single action that I get/update a UI component a single delegate. It is not a very readable and cosy solution (i would have preferred use just a delegate) but... it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your program to continue executing when the Timer_Function() code is run you could use a Task.Run to perform the work on a worker thread.

As always with parallel execution you need to beware of synchronization issues. Make sure you don't need the results before the work is processed and dispathed. Using the dispatcher as you mentioned might be enough, just make sure you think it through.

Something like:

```
Timer_Function()
{ 
     Task.Run(() => 
     {
          /* do your work here */
     });
}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your issue

Comment: He doesn't need code to move work to a non-UI thread.  He *starts out* in a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous tasks, use this -

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  // Code which needs to run asynchronously
}.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        {
          // Code in which you are updating UI
        });
    }
```

Comment: He doesn't need code to move work to a non-UI thread. He *starts out* in a non-UI thread.